# Is there a way in EWL to dynamically set the title of the page based on my location?

Tags: c#, web-applications, page-title, enterprise-web-library

The title (in this case I care about the text showing up on the Tab of Firefox) of my page is always the long name of the system, and then my location tacked onto the end of it. I'm in a situation where I want to kind of have two sites under the same umbrella and I'd like to show a different base title when appropriate. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `EwfApp.AppDisplayName` in your `Global.asax` class.

Comment: Is there a recommended way of choosing which display name to use, besides "if( Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains( "/sectionOfSite" ) )"?

Comment: @GregSmalter: You could grab `EwfPage.Instance.InfoAsBaseType` and then look recursively for a certain parent. Or, if you definitely want to use the URL, I'd recommend using that `Info` object to get it instead of using `Request`; the `Info` will always give you the canonical URL for the page you're on.